# In some devices when using the Navigation drawer the up caret does not get replaced by the application icon

Tags: android, android-styles, android-navigation

I downloaded the code provided for Navigation Drawer as mentioned at [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

I tried it on a few devices and the **application icon + drawer icon** combo replaces the up caret icon

But on one of my devices running on `4.2.1` the caret shows up.

The device is *Lenovo K900* with Full HD display rest of the devices I checked had lesser resolution.

I tried adding the style

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
```

but even that did not help.

Is it with this device or some other configuration is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` right after the following code.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```